# How to structure UI Test methods to reach pages that are behind the login page?

Tags: xctest, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest, uitest

I am trying to find best practices on how to structure UI Test methods in XCTestCase to reach and test app pages that are accessible only after the user logs in.

For me to be able to test the UI of a private Photo View page my test method will need to: 
 1. Login, 
 2. Go to the "Albums List" page,
 3. Tap on the first album in the list and go to the "Album View" page, 
 4. Tap on the first photo in the list and go to "Photo View" page,
 5. And finally, write assertions to test the UI of a Photo View page.

So, to read the destination page, my UI test needs to go through multiple pages. And if I need to write several UI Test methods for the Photo View Page, then each of my test methods will need to go through the same app pages again and again.

What are the best practices to structure my test methods to test internal app pages?

Shoudl I follow the BDD to do that and write a base class with a method:

```
givenThatLoginIsSuccessful()
```

and then create a new Test Case class that extends the base class and has methods like:

```
// Given
givenThatLoginIsSuccessful()
givenThanAlbumsListPageHasAlbums()
giveThatAlbumViewPageHasPhotos()

// When
whenThumbnailPhotoTapped()

// Then 
thenLargeSizePhotoIsVisible()
thenDismissLargePhotoButtonIsEnabled()
thenDownloadLargePhotoButtonIsEnabled()
```

How do you guys organize your UI Test methods that test internal/deep app pages?

Answer (score 2):

I usually organise my code with PageObject (ScreenObject) pattern.
https://github.com/rzakhar/xctest-assignment/blob/master/TestTarget/TestClass.swift

You can see another implementation of this pattern in this question [XCUITest using Robot pattern can't print the erroneous line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60841886/xcuitest-using-robot-pattern-cant-print-the-erroneous-line)

There are also other techniques – and they shall be chosen regarding the tests.

Comment: thank you! I will have a look at the links you have shared.